# Combine several DataTables DataRows

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Dataset of DataTables with same structure. I want to get a single collection of DataRows from these tables in **SINGLE** linq query

```
from sourceTab in ds.Tables.OfType<DataTable>() 
select sourceTab
```

Then I need to select datarows from each table and combine them into one list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` to select all rows from each table and flatten them into one sequence:

```
from row in ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().SelectMany(t => t.AsEnumerable())
// filter, etc 
select row
```

If you just want all rows, then use

```
ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().SelectMany(t => t.AsEnumerable())
```

Answer (score 2):

You don' need query syntax to do that. Simple method query is fine:

```
var results = ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().SelectMany(t => t.AsEnumerable())
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`Cast<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) and [`SelectMany<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)

```
var r = ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().SelectMany(n => n.AsEnumerable())
```